# Subdomains in Mandrill

Tags: mandrill

I am using Mandrill trial account for sending emails, i have a question which i am not able to find a solution.

I have a domain (www.domain.com) which is registered with Mandrill account with an email address email1@domain.com. I have a requirement where i have to sent emails from different sub domains from mandrill. Is there any facility to configure sub domains or wildcard DNS in Mandrill. Basically i want to sent email from different email addresses like email1@subdomain1.domain.com, email2@subdomain2.domain.com, email3@subdomain3.domain.com.

Here the sub domains can be anything which changes for different users, but the main domain doesn't change. Is there ant way to achieve this.

Please help me, I am new to Mandrill.

Answer (score 0):

Since you own the domain and thus also the email server,

1. go to your email settings
2. forward/reroute email2@subdomain2.domain.com to email2@domain.com
3. receive verification link on email2@domain.com
4. verify and use the application